# How to invoke app.js function from html page in expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to invoke `function init() { // }` present in app.js  from html  page  from

```
<a href='javascript:init();'> invoke init </a>
```

The problem with the above code is, that it looks for `function init()` only at the client side, whereas I want to invoke `function init()` at the express server app.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite using the same language, client and server have no direct ties to each other. They're still bound to communicating with HTTP or WebSockets.

So, you'll need to establish a route that will call `init()` when requested:

```
app.get('/init', function (req, res) {
    init();
    // res.send(...), etc.
});
```

Then have the client either navigate to it:

```
<a href="/init"> invoke init </a>
```

Or, request it via [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX):

```
function init() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/init');
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: How can i do it using websockets?

Comment: @Swagg Node.js doesn't pre-define support for the WebSocket protocol like it does with HTTP, so you'll need to find a library/framework that implements it on top of the `net` module. Probably the most common is [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/), but there are certainly others.

Comment: can something like angularjs be used for it?

Comment: @Swagg I don't believe Angular defines any modules for WebSockets, specifically. But, it can be used along with Socket.IO or the native [`WebSocket` class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).